# Remove cell tags when converting a jupyter notebook into a python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert a jupyter notebook to python script. Everything works except those cell tags (I believe) `In[84]:`, `In[80]:`. I tried `trp.remove_cell_tags = ("remove_cell",)` but no luck. What's the best way to remove these strings?

```
# In[8]:


eco = pd.read_csv(here('./data/eco.csv'))


# In[68]:


eco.head(20)


# In[40]:


# Plot two variables but it's likely to suffer ecological fallacy bias - missing out confounding variables
plt.scatter(eco.usborn, eco.income)
plt.ylabel("Income")
plt.xlabel("Fraction US born")


# In[25]:
```

```
import nbformat as nbf
from nbconvert.exporters import PythonExporter
from nbconvert.preprocessors import TagRemovePreprocessor

here()
with open("notebooks/mynotebook.ipynb", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    the_notebook_nodes = nbf.read(f, as_version = 4)

trp = TagRemovePreprocessor()

trp.remove_cell_tags = ("remove_cell",)
trp.remove_input_tags = ("remove_input",)
trp.remove_all_outputs_tags = ('remove_output',)
trp.enabled = True

pexp = PythonExporter()

pexp.register_preprocessor(trp, enabled= True)

the_python_script, meta = pexp.from_notebook_node(the_notebook_nodes)

with open("a_python_script.py", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines(the_python_script)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a using any IDE, its "find and replace"-function does probably support regular expressions. With it you could replace `# In.*` by nothing, which worked fine with my IDE and your code.

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but it may be a a sufficient solution for your problem :)

Comment: This is a good suggestion as I am using Sublime, so I guess I can do regular rexpresson to remove those lines.